# Memory requirement for android

Tags: android, memory, google-play

I have an android game which is a bit heavy on memory (normal usage at 280MB, peaks at 380MB) and I'd like to know if there's a way to limit the devices which can download the game in Google Play by the amount of memory. (as openGL can be limited to 2.0 or 3.0 in example, limiting my game to 1GB devices)

thanks!

Comment: I looked through all the relevant documentation, and couldn't find anything either. So the answer might simply be "no, it's not possible". The most relevant article I came across beyond the manifest documentation is this: http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html. No mention of memory limits that I can find.

Comment: That's pretty weird, isn't it? I mean... if my game just crashes out of memory because it's too resource intensive, what can I do? Just sit down for 1 star ratings? :)